# Is there way to set stability filter for alerts in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a service that pushes forecast metrics every 1 minute to Prometheus using a push gateway and configured an alert rule in Prometheus.

Requirements:

- 5 minutes is the stability filter.
- If forecasts are not published over the last 5 minutes, then trigger a firing alert.
- If forecasts are published over the last 5 minutes, then resolve the alert.

The reason we need a stability filter is: sometimes the service is not able to push metrics due to the push gateway service being down for 1 minute and the push gateway service being recovered within 2 minutes, so we do not want to send firing alerts in this scenario.

**Prometheus configurations:**

evaluation_interval: 1m

scrape_interval: 30s

**Alert rule:**

```
- alert: forecaster
  expr: rate(forecasts_published_counter{job=\"metrics_job\", module_name=\"forecaster\"}[5m]) <= 0
  for: 5m
```

I experimented stability filter using **FOR clause**, it works for firing alerts but it does not work for resolving alerts.

***The service is not publishing forecasts for over the 5 minutes:***

- The time taken to change the alert state from **inactive** to **pending** is 1m i.e evaluation interval.
- The time taken to change the alert state from **pending** to **firing** is between **(FOR clause interval)** and **(evaluation_interval + scrape_interval + FOR clause interval)** i.e 5m and (1m + 30s + 5m = 6m 30s).

***The service publishing forecasts over the 5 minutes:***

- The time taken to change the alert state from firing to inactive (Resolved) is 1m i.e evaluation interval.

I can change the evaluation interval to 5m but it affects other services. So I do not want to change it.

**Is there any other way to set a stability filter (5m) in Prometheus for changing the alert state from firing to inactive(Resolved)?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [absent_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent_over_time) function to check if Prometheus has recieved specified metric for the last 5 minutes.

```
- alert: forecaster
  expr: absent_over_time(forecasts_published_counter{job=\"metrics_job\", module_name=\"forecaster\"}[5m])
```

If your metrics will be missing for 5 minutes `absent_over_time` will return pseudometric with your labels, and alert will be fired.

Once your metric will appear again `absent_over_time` will return nothing, and alert will be resolved.

Since in this case you don't have `for:`  clause in the alert rule - there will not be **pending**  status. But firing of alert will not happen exactly after 5 minutes of missing metric, but rather 5 minutes + some time (depending on `evaluation_interval`).

If you want firing time closer to 5 minutes you could set time for `absent_over_time` equals to something like `5m - evaluation_interval/2 - scrape_interval/2` (manually calc depending on your config), I believe in your case `4m15s`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

absent_over_time works if the metric name does not exist.  In my case, the metric name will be there in Prometheus but the metric value won't be coming from the service.

Comment: `absent_over_time` works depending on the time range provided. It will return something, only if at provided time-range metric wasn't updated. You can check example [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=absent_over_time(up%20%5B1m%5D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=15m&g0.end_input=2023-03-14%2014%3A09%3A25&g0.moment_input=2023-03-14%2014%3A09%3A25)

Comment: The service was up for 5 minutes and pushed metrics, then the service was down for 5 minutes and did not push metrics to Prometheus for the last 5 minutes. 
The following is my query result.
Query: 
forecasts_published_counter{job="metrics_job", module_name="forecaster"}[10m]
Result:
1 
2 
3 
4
5 
5 
5 
5 
5 
5   
If I query the last 5 minutes, the below query should return because no metrics are pushed for the last 5 minutes, the metric value is 5 for the last 5 minutes.

absent_over_time(forecasts_published_counter{job="metrics_job", module_name="forecaster"}[5m])

Comment: @shivakumarsajjan Try to check with smaller time range.

Comment: but absent_over_time query is not returning any result. Please suggest me if i am doing wrong here

Comment: I tried the 10s time range, the query returns the result. But I do not understand why query does not return for 5 minutes. Should metric be gauge type?

Comment: Metric type should not matter. Maybe due to low absence time some kind of "auto stretching" here at play.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252540/discussion-between-shivakumar-sajjan-and-markalex).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- alert: forecaster
  expr: time()-timestamp(forecasts_published_counter{job=\"metrics_job\", module_name=\"forecaster\"}) > 5 * 60
  annotations:
    description: "Forecast has not been updated for {{ $value }} seconds"
```

Logic of previous answer about scrape and evaluation time applies here too.